# Facebook: Can mobile feed dialogs be customized?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to create a post to a user's wall via my facebook connect mobile app. I looked [on the FB developer's website](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#web) and only found this to post through mobile:

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&display=touch`

along with this statement ***The current version of the JavaScript SDK does not yet supporting automatically selecting the correct dialog for the user's device. We expect to add this capability shortly.***

Has this been fixed yet? I have been trying to workaround using the normal method:

```
//Post on user's wall
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'MyApp',
    link: 'myURL',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: caption,
    description: message,
    message: ''
},
function (response) {

});
```

But it is slow and doesn't work the way I want it to.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now no the cannot. You can still do auto publish posts though.